# HTTP PUT method on NodeMCU

Tags: esp8266, c++, nodemcu, http

I am trying to update values to Firebase. According to Firebase:

```sh
curl -X PUT -d '{ "first": "Jack", "last": "Sparrow" }' \
  'https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/users/jack/name.json'
```

We can update using put command. Using curl works fine, but when I look at the header of `ESP8266HTTPClient`, I don't see any `put` or `patch` method there.

I can only see the following:

```cpp
int GET();
int POST(uint8_t * payload, size_t size);
int POST(String payload);
```

Whereas in NodeMCU documentation, it is clearly stated it supports the `put` method too.

```lua
http.put(url, headers, body, callback)
```

[`http.put()` documentation](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/http/#httpput)

I cannot find any example.

How can I implement the `put` method in NodeMCU?

Comment: Just because NodeMCU's Lua HTTP library has a PUT method, doesn't mean Arduino's C++ HTTP library has it too.

Comment: Also you are only using the NodeMCU board not the firmware, so "implementing the put method in nodemcu" makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pardon me if i asked too soon. I found the answer. 
all verb are supported. but `post` and `get` got their own names.

```
 int httpCode = http.sendRequest("PUT", String(data));
```

enven post method implement the sendRequest.